# SVG as background image in React Native

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) to insert SVG images into my React Native app.
I'm currently replacing my pngs by svgs because of the blurriness of most of my assets. I came to a use case where I need to replace an `ImageBackground`, that uses png by an SVG file. Is there a way to do this? I tried to use the image as a main component with all my elements inside but the image appears on top of everything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-svg-uri`

Example

```js
  <SvgUri
      width="200"
      height="200"
      source={{uri:'http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg'}}
      source={require('./simpson.svg')}
    />
```

Comment: And my svg is not online its a file

Comment: @ThéoLavaux It can also be used as an image path for a file. `require("./simpson.svg")`

Comment: Did you run into this kind of error before https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/571? This is exactly what I have using this technique

Comment: @ThéoLavaux When I used the module I wrote in my answer, I never caused such an error. Have you checked the SVG file you are using by converting it into a png file?

Comment: I tried of using it. Two issues i am facing. 1 . it is not acting as a background  2. it don't have option to set auto height